# Direct to base nested react route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to have a link that will direct me to the base nested route, for instance I have the URL "app/dashboard" within the dashboard UI I want to have a link the will direct me to the base nested URL which is "app/dashboard". When I use the "/" in the 'to' attribute it directs me to the root base which is "app".

**Index.js**

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />  
    </Route>
    <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="upload-reciept" element={<UploadReciept />} />
      <Route path="upload-details" element={<UploadDetails />} />
    </Route> 
</Routes>
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
<ul className="space-y-2">
   <li>
      <NavLink to="/" className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? "bg-sky-200 text-sky-700" : "hover:bg-sky-200 hover:text-sky-700"}>
         <HomeIcon className="h-5 w-5 sm:h-6 sm:w-6"/>
         <span>Home</span>
      </NavLink>
   </li>
   <li>
      <NavLink to="upload-reciept"  className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? "bg-sky-200 text-sky-700" : "hover:bg-sky-200 hover:text-sky-700"}>
         <CloudUploadIcon className="h-5 w-5 sm:h-6 sm:w-6"/>    
         <span>Upload reciept</span>
      </NavLink>
   </li>
   <li>
      <NavLink to="upload-details"  className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? "bg-sky-200 text-sky-700" : "hover:bg-sky-200 hover:text-sky-700"}>
         <RefreshIcon className="h-5 w-5 sm:h-6 sm:w-6" />
         <span>Update details</span>
      </NavLink>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How do I go about directing the "Home" link to "app/dashboard"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"."` as the link target to target the current "directory" path `"/dashboard"`. Add the `end` prop for this link so it's only active when the path ends with the path the link is targeting, i.e. `"/dashboard"`.

```
<NavLink
  to="."
  end // <-- to match path "/dashboard"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive
      ? "bg-sky-200 text-sky-700"
      : "hover:bg-sky-200 hover:text-sky-700"
  }
>
  <HomeIcon className="h-5 w-5 sm:h-6 sm:w-6" />
  <span>Home</span>
</NavLink>
```

[image: Edit direct-to-base-nested-react-route]

Comment: This works, however "isActive" is always true. Even if I have clicked on another link.

Comment: @M_Magz Oh, you likely just need to use the `end` prop on this root dashboard link then. Tested and updated sandbox.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on the "end" prop?

Comment: @M_Magz [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink) There's a little blurb - "If the end prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to render a link that is only active at the website root and not any other URLs, you can use: `<NavLink to="/" end>Home</NavLink>`"

Answer (score 0):

you didnt define /app route
you have to way
at first step you can define nested Route like this

```
    <Routes>
         <Route to="/app" element={<App/>}>
         <Route to="dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}>
              //other <Route/>
         </Route>
       </Route>
    <Routes>
```

or you can use the old way (before v6)
and you even can define route as a hard code and define exact Route to react
like : `<Route to="/where/ever/you/want" {...props} />`
for other thing check the document of react-router-dom
its very easy
goodluck dude!!!

Comment: OP didn't say they needed an `"/app"` route. This answer doesn't address OP's issue with using the link to get to the `"/dashboard"` route.